# Why is it possible to pass in key value pairs to a function that destructures a map?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I thought I understood destructuring, but I was reading a clojure blog and this confused me.  If you have a function written like:

```
(defn f [& {:keys [foo bar]}] 
  (println foo " " bar))
```

Why can you call it like this:

```
(f :foo 1 :bar 2)
```

My first thought was that my function was supposed to be called like this:

```
(f {:foo 1 :bar 2})
IllegalArgumentException No value supplied for key: {:foo 1, :bar 2}  clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.createWithCheck (PersistentHashMap.java:89)
```

But obviously that doesn't work.  I think this has something to do with the way `&` works.  But I always thought that the thing after it is a vector and therefore you'd have to destructure anything after it like a vector.

Can someone explain to me how/why this definition works the way it does? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The & and destructuring form work sequentially:

- The & gathers any arguments after it into a collection
- The map destructuring form then takes the collection, **makes a map out of it if required** and binds the names to the keys listed in the vector.

The vector in the map destructuring form is just syntax used to build the desctructuring/binding and does not imply anything aobut the input form

The without the & in the defn the second form will work and the first will not.
With the & the first form will work and the second will not.

Comment: "The vector in the map destructuring form is just syntax" - indeed, a list will work equally well here.

Answer (score 7):

You can see what's going on under the covers by calling `destructure` manually. Let's start with a simpler example:

```
user> (destructure ['{foo :foo} {:foo 42}])
[map__26147 {:foo 42}
 map__26147 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__26147)
              (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create
               (clojure.core/seq map__26147))
              map__26147)
 foo (clojure.core/get map__26147 :foo)]
```

This corresponds to `(let [{foo :foo} {:foo 42}] ...)` (as you can verify with `(macroexpand-1 '(let [{foo :foo} {:foo 42}] ...))`. The second line of the output is the important bit. A map binding form can work in two ways: if the value being bound is a seq, the seq will be 'poured' into a hash-map (as if by `(apply hash-map the-seq)`. Otherwise, the value is assumed to be an associative and used directly. The seq 'pouring' feature was added in [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/29389970bcd41998359681d9a4a20ee391a1e07c).

Let's test this out:

```
user> (let [{foo :foo} {:foo 42}] foo)
42
user> (let [{foo :foo} (list :foo 42)] foo)
42
user> (let [{foo :foo} (apply hash-map (list :foo 42))] foo)
42
```

In the first case, the value is not a seq, so it's used directly. In the second case, a list is a seq, so it is 'poured' into a hash-map before being bound to `{foo :foo}`. The third case shows that this pouring is semantically equivalent to `(apply hash-map the-seq)`.

Now let's look at something like your example:

```
user> (destructure '[[& {:keys [foo bar]}] args])
[vec__26204 args
 map__26205 (clojure.core/nthnext vec__26204 0)
 map__26205 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__26205)
              (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create
               (clojure.core/seq map__26205))
              map__26205)
 bar (clojure.core/get map__26205 :bar)
 foo (clojure.core/get map__26205 :foo)]
```

The `nthnext` bit is from the `&` — in this case, because there are no fixed parameters before the `&`, we have an `(nthnext vec# 0)`, which amounts to just converting `args` into a seq (if necessary). Then we have the map destructuring as above. Because the `&` guarantees we have a seq, the seq special case for map destructuring will always be triggered, and the args will always be 'poured' into a hash-map before being bound to the map form.

In case the relationship between this example and your original fn is not clear, consider:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(fn [& {:keys [foo bar]}]))
(fn* ([& p__26214] (clojure.core/let [{:keys [foo bar]} p__26214])))
```